# comparing Json result from a function in robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Trying to create a test case in robot framework .

We have couple of rest apis which returns us Json as result . To invoke such a case, we used the following code in rest2.py

```
def restJSON():
    r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
#    print "Code" , r.status_code
#    print "Text " , r.text
    return r.json()
```

We stored the json inside a file output. And we have written robot test case to evaluate json comparison as below

```
*** Settings ***
 Library   rest2.py
 Library   OperatingSystem
*** Test Cases ***
 Example that calls a python keyword
  ${result}=   restJSON
  ${json}=   Get file   output
  Should be equal   ${result}   ${json}
```

But when we run the pybot test case we are getting error saying both json are not same.

```
--------------------------------
pybot testSuite.txt
--------------------------------
==============================================================================
testSuite
==============================================================================
Example that calls a python keyword                                   | FAIL |
{u'origin': u'10.252.30.94, 69.241.25.16', u'headers': {u'Via': u'1.1 localhost (squid/3.1.14)', u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress', u'Accept': u'*/*', u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.16.0-30-generic', u'Host': u'httpbin.org', u'Cache-Control': u'max-age=259200'}, u'args': {}, u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/get'} != {u'origin': u'10.252.30.94, 69.241.25.16', u'headers': {u'Via': u'1.1 localhost (squid/3.1.14)', u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress', u'Accept': u'*/*', u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.16.0-30-generic', u'Host': u'httpbin.org', u'Cache-Control': u'max-age=259200'}, u'args': {}, u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/get'}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
testSuite                                                             | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

The json file are same. But still its Failing test case saying both aren't same. Is this the correct way to compare , or do we have any other method to do it in robot framework.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using the already existing libraries:

Example code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                     RequestsLibrary
Library                     Collections
Library                     XML  use_lxml=True
Force Tags                  REST


*** Variables ***
${SERVICE_ROOT}  http://ip.jsontest.com/
${SERVICE_NAME}  testing

*** Keywords ***
json_property_should_equal
    [Arguments]  ${json}  ${property}  ${value_expected}
    ${value_found} =    Get From Dictionary  ${json}  ${property}
    ${error_message} =  Catenate  SEPARATOR=  Expected value for property "  ${property}  " was "  ${value_expected}  " but found "  ${value_found}  "
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${value_found}  ${value_expected}  ${error_message}    values=false

*** Test Cases ***
Example REST JSON
  Create session  ${SERVICE_NAME}  ${SERVICE_ROOT}
  ${headers}=  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json  Accept=application/json
  ${result}=  Get Request  ${SERVICE_NAME}  ${SERVICE_ROOT}  headers=${headers}
  Should Be Equal  ${result.status_code}  ${200}
  Log  ${result.content}
  ${json}=    To Json    ${result.content}
  ${pp}=  To Json  ${result.content}  pretty_print=True
  Log  ${pp}
  json_property_should_equal  ${json}  ip  [Your_IP]
```

Remember to install all needed libraries:

```
pip install robotframework-requests
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the response when you do:

```
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${result}   ${json}
```

I find your method for achieving what you want a bit strange, if I were you I would be using the http-library or requests library

https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary
https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests

Answer (score 2):

`Get File` reads the content of the file and returns a string; in the same time the python function returns a dict object. So looks like you are comparing a dict to a string - and they simply can't return equal.

If you convert the file output to a dict, then the check will most probably pass:

```
# your other code
${json_file}=   Get file   output
${json_file}=   Evaluate   json.loads("""${json_file}""")    json     # use the json module to transform str->dict

Should Be Equal    ${result}    ${json_file}

# even better - more verbose logging if values differ, or there are missing keys:
Dictionaries Should Be Equal    ${result}    ${json_file}
```

Comment: THE answer to OP's question!

Answer (score 0):

working examples

put this in a .robot file

```
*** Settings ***
Library    jsonlib.py

*** Variables ***
${response_json}    {"key1": 33, "key2": "string", "key3": [1,2,3,"sring"], "name": "hans"}
${expected_json}    {"key1": 77, "key2": "string", "key3": [1,2,3,"sring"], "name": "OTTO", "age": 33}

*** Test Cases ***
response meets expectation
    &{json1}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${response_json}''')    json
    &{json2}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${expected_json}''')    json
    Log Dictionary    ${json1}
    Log Dictionary    ${json2}
    # ${type}=    evaluate    type(${json1}).__name__
    # ${type}=    evaluate    type(&{json2})
    response_meets_expectation  ${json1}  ${json2}

compare json payloads
    &{json1}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${response_json}''')    json
    &{json2}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${expected_json}''')    json
    compare_json_payloads  ${json1}  ${json2}

json payloads should match
    &{json1}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${response_json}''')    json
    &{json2}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${expected_json}''')    json
    json_paylodas_should_match  ${json1}  ${json2}
```

put this in jsonlib.py in same folder as the .robot file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import jsondiff
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
# from deepdiff import DeepSearch, grep
from pprint import pprint
from robot.api import logger


class JsonCompareError(Exception):
    pass

def response_meets_expectation(response, expectation):
    union = jsondiff.patch(response, expectation)
    difference = jsondiff.diff(response, union)
    if difference:
            raise JsonCompareError("Diff found: {}".format(difference))
    else:
        return True

def compare_json_payloads(response_json, expected_json):
    logger.debug("Compare JSON payloads")
    diff = DeepDiff(response_json, expected_json, ignore_order=True, verbose_level=2)
    logger.debug("Values changed: {}".format(diff['values_changed']))
    return diff.to_dict()

def json_paylodas_should_match(response_json, expected_json):
    diff = DeepDiff(response_json, expected_json, verbose_level=2)
    if diff != {}:
        raise JsonCompareError("Payloads do not match! Differences: {}".format(diff))
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba it would be something like:

```
Library         Zoomba.APILibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test
   ${headers}=  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json  Accept=application/json
   ${actual_response}=   Call Get Request   ${headers}    http://httpbin.org/get
   Validate Response Contains Expected Response     ${actual_response}    ${expected_response}
```

This will go key by key to validate the results, anything that fails will appear like so:

```
Key(s) Did Not Match:
------------------
Key: pear
Expected: fish
Actual: bird
------------------
Full List Breakdown:
Expected: [{'apple': 'cat', 'banana': 'dog', 'pear': 'fish'}, {'apple': 'cat', 'banana': 'mice', 'pear': 'bird'}, {'apple': 'dog', 'banana': 'mice', 'pear': 'cat'}]
Actual: [{'apple': 'cat', 'banana': 'dog', 'pear': 'bird'}]

Please see differing value(s)"
```

Docs here: https://accruent.github.io/robotframework-zoomba/docs/APILibraryDocumentation.html